# Graphs where every vertex can be its own color class

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite, simple, undirected graph.  We say $G$ has the *singleton coloring class property* (SCCP) if for all $v_0\in V$ there is a vertex coloring $c:V\to\{1,\ldots,\chi(G)\}$ such that no vertex other than $v_0$ receives the same color as $v_0$, that is, $c^{-1}\big(\{c(v_0)\}\big) =\{v_0\}$.

If a graph $G$ is connected and $G$ has the SCCP, does this imply that $G$ is complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick counter example look at odd cycles.

These graphs are called [(vertex) critical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_graph). You can look into the Hajós construction, which produces larger critical graphs from smaller ones without changing the chromatic number.